# How to create ActiveModel Object in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I am having the following model class on ActiveRecord. How to write an equivalent ActiveModel for this class?

```
class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.columns() @columns ||= []; end

  def self.column(name, sql_type = nil, default = nil, null = true)
    columns << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(name.to_s, default, sql_type.to_s, null)
  end

  column :from_email, :string
  column :to_email, :string
  column :article_id, :integer
  column :message, :text
  serialize :exception

  validates_format_of :from_email, :to_email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
  validates_length_of :message, :maximum => 500

  belongs_to :article
end
```

Comment: Why ? Is `Recommendation` not database backed ?

Comment: Its just a temporary object. I am destroying the object as soon as the expected task completed. I dont want to store those data in db.

Comment: right, `ActiveModel` is a good choice for this as then you would not have to destroy it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with a plain class, and then start adding in ActiveModel modules. Say, start with validation.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html

```
class Recommendation
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :from_email, :to_email, :article_id, :message

  validates_format_of :from_email, :to_email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
  validates_length_of :message, :maximum => 500
end
```

The other ActiveModel docs can be found at http://api.rubyonrails.org/